# Showing error "end of statement expected"

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am making a report on the amount paid and the target amount, and I want to include a line with indicators. Following is the code for the indicator; however, when I save it shows me the error `end of statement expected`. Can anyone please help, I am new to Visual Basic.

```
Function KPI Indicator(AmtPaid As Decimal, TargetAmt As  Decimal) As String Select Case 

    AmtPaid/TargetAmt

    Case Is>= 1.5
        Return "Green" 

    Case Is>=.90
        Return "Yellow"

    Case Else
        Return "Red"

    End Select 

End Function
```

Comment: Is the code you put in your Q the exact same as the code in your project? If so, it's full of syntax errors.

Comment: Yes, that is the code in my project. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you copied and pasted your code and it turned out badly, but you have several syntax errors. Try this:

```
Function KPIIndicator(AmtPaid As Decimal, TargetAmt As  Decimal) As String 

    Select Case (AmtPaid/TargetAmt)  'select case was in the same line as the function declaration and didn't have anything following it.

    Case Is>= 1.5
        Return "Green" 

    Case Is>=.90
        Return "Yellow"

    Case Else
        Return "Red"

    End Select 

End Function
```

Comment: Try deleting the space between KPI and Indicator. Did that help?

Comment: No change! I have another function running at the top (which is correct and is working), do you think that is the problem??

Comment: yeah, you probably are going to have to post all the code in that module, or just look up what the syntax errors mean.

Comment: Public Function GetValue(Item,Item2, RowNum) 

If RowNum = 1 then
PaidValue = 0
TargetValue  = 0
end if


if IsNothing(Item) then
TargetValue = TargetValue + Item2
return TargetValue
end if


if IsNothing(Item2) then

PaidValue = PaidValue + Item
return PaidValue

end if

End Function

Comment: Sorry, but you'd have to format that _exactly_ as it appears in your program into your question. There's no way to tell if anythings wrong with all that text.

Comment: Your function has no data type, a function must always have a data type as in `Public Function Explain(Parameter as integer) as integer`
Thats just the first thing i spotted, i dont see any decelerations for PaidValue, TargetValue either.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function KPI_Indicator(AmtPaid As Decimal, TargetAmt As  Decimal) As String
    Select Case AmtPaid/TargetAmt
    Case Is>= 1.5
        Return "Green" 

    Case Is>=0.9
        Return "Yellow"

    Case Else
        Return "Red"

    End Select 
End Function
```

First, name of function can't contain spaces. Second, `Select Case` was in same line as Function declaration and `AmtPaid/TargetAmt` was is different line. Third, you must use `0.9` instead of `.9`. If you are still getting errors, you'll have to post more code.